# TokenAuthentication: Not able to authenticate

Tags: django, rest, authentication

I am trying to implement [`TokenAuthentication`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) from Django rest framework.
I am able to get the Token key from server,

```
$curl -d "username=admin&password=admin"  http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/
{"token":"a571a596eab2e4063da4b9250a05b570ba8e9786"}
```

But **I am not able to get use it with any api**,

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/cart/ -H "Authorization: Token a571a596eab2e4063da4b9250a05b570ba8e9786"
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

My Setting file,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'myapp',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
#rest framework
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the TokenAuthentication backend in

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
```

Just add the `rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication` line. Keep in mind that the order matters as authentication backends are sequentially tested.

Comment: It works !!. I had same doubt. We have class for basic authentication & session authentication. In documentation none was given for token authentication. Thanks !!

Comment: drf works always the same way for authentication backends, filtering, permissions, etc. Glad it helped =).